# when pulling a git repo, netbeans prompts me for reverting my changes instead of openning the 'merge changes' dialog

Tags: git, netbeans

I have always a problem with #netbeans v8.2 and #git.

When I have local changes (along with remote conflicting changes on the server) and try to pull (by right-clicking on the project and select git>remote>pull), #netbeans just prompts me asking to revert my changes before doing the pull (no other option). There is no compare and merge dialog (the famous three-part dialog).

What am I missing in my pulling process?

I'm not experienced with git, but I've used #netbeans for years (subversion projects).

Comment: It seems you have not committed local changes. The changes are not tracked by Git yet. When the conflicts come about at git-pull, Git has no right to overwrite the local changes or choose them instead of the remote revision.

Comment: That's the point dear @ElpieKay . I am still thinking svn-style I think ;) why not posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ElpieKay;

It was because i had not committed my changes before pull.

I'm used to subversion and thought I have to commit after merging remote modifies. Now I know that when it comes to git, I have to :

1. Commit my changes to local repo
2. pull
3. Resolve conflicts (if any)
4. Commit resolved conflicts (if any)
5. And finally push

It still sounds a bit strange to me. I have to commit my changes regardless of what others have done. I have to resolve conflicts while I have not my IDE showing each modified row with specific color(blue, green, gray).